# Netlogo, Altering the location of label

Tags: netlogo

I am just curious if it's possible to alter the location of the labels in NetLogo. For example in the image below the word "La Grande Soufriere", is it possible to move it above the breed instead of below (as you can see it gets in the way of the other agents. Another case is the Habitants PMA (Actual name is Vieux Habitants) but only half of its name has appeared since the rest of its off-screen. I tried to manually type on a close-by patch but since I have used a fill color, it doesn't appear at all (it's covered by the fill color if you know what I mean). Does anyone have a solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I am just curious if it's possible to alter the location of the labels in NetLogo.

The short answer is that it is not possible.

The slightly longer answer is that there are ways around it, but they're not very satisfying.

If you want to alter the horizontal location, you can pad your label with spaces at the end or the beginning of the string to move it left or right, respectively.

If you want to alter the vertical location, or have more control over it, you can always create a "dummy" turtle to display the label. You can hide the dummy turtle without hidding its label by setting the `size` of the turtle to zero or by creating an empty turtle shape and using that for it.

I don't think it matters in your case, since you seem to want to label only stationary turtles, but if you wanted a dummy to move with a particular turtle, you can create a hidden link between them and [`tie`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#tie) them.

There might be other creative ways to deal with labels (and I'd be curious to read about them in other answers), but that's all I can think of for now.

Comment: I didn't want to put this in the main answer, but you can also use links (but not turtles, see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/325) to stamp (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#stamp) labels into the drawing layer.